# How will I execute another SELECT command after I executed the first one?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sqlcommand, selectcommand

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string client = TextBox1.Text;
        string selected = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
        string calendar = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        string disease = txtDisease.Text;

        SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("insert into Appointment(Client_ID, DateofAppointment, TimeofAppointment, Disease) values(@Client_ID, @DateofAppointment, @TimeofAppointment, @Disease)", conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Client where Client_ID = @Client_ID", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client_ID", TextBox1.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {       
                    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client_ID", client);
                    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofAppointment", calendar);
                    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeofAppointment", selected);
                    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Disease", disease);
                    insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    TextBox1.Text = "";
                    RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    txtDisease.Text = "";
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Appointment submitted! Please wait for your SMS confirmation. Thank you!')</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "";
                RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = -1;
                txtDisease.Text = "";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('You are not a registered client!')</script>");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }


}
```

I want to create another command to search if the date and tie is already taken before inserting it to my db.

Comment: Create a 2nd command object and call it,just like the first one

Comment: even better why don't you write a stored procedure and everything gets executed in one go?

Comment: Can you show me how? I tried creating another command before the insert.parameters but it's not working.

Comment: What is the goal? To see if date and time is not taken and then insert ?

Comment: Yes. The system should not accept if the date and time is already taken.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your original exception was but it is helpful to include that when posting a question.

Also about your connection, class level connections are usually not recommended. Sql Server handles connection pooling for you so best practice is to dispose your connection as soon as you are done using it. When you want to requery (in another method or class) then create a new connection. Also wrap your connections in `using` blocks to ensure they are closed and disposed.

And regarding your date, it is best to always persist data in its native type. This means that your column type  for your date should be a Sql Date, not a string. This also means your parameter value for your calendar should be `DateTime calendar = Calendar1.SelectedDate;` and not `string`.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string client = TextBox1.Text;
    string selected = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;

    // this should be a DateTime instance, not a string
    string calendar = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();

    string disease = txtDisease.Text;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select 1 from Appointment WHERE DateofAppointment = @DateofAppointment AND TimeofAppointment = @TimeofAppointment", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofAppointment", calendar);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeofAppointment", selected);
        bool exists = false;
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
           exists = reader.Read(); // if this returns true there is a record
        }

        // do something based on exists

        SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("insert into Appointment(Client_ID, DateofAppointment, TimeofAppointment, Disease) values(@Client_ID, @DateofAppointment, @TimeofAppointment, @Disease)", conn);

        // repurpose same pointer but to different instance
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Client where Client_ID = @Client_ID", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client_ID", TextBox1.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {       
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client_ID", client);
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofAppointment", calendar);
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeofAppointment", selected);
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Disease", disease);
                insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                TextBox1.Text = "";
                RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = -1;
                txtDisease.Text = "";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Appointment submitted! Please wait for your SMS confirmation. Thank you!')</script>");
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = -1;
            txtDisease.Text = "";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('You are not a registered client!')</script>");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to check if the date and time are available,irrespective of the clientID i.e. select 1 from Appointment WHERE DateofAppointment = @DateofAppointment" AND TimeofAppointment = @TimeofAppointment

Answer (score 0):

You can create a command before your first one and check the result before executing the second:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Client where {you conditions}";
Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

And then check if `count` is greater than 0 then execute the second.

Comment: I posted it please check. I need this to wooork. :/

Comment: you are missing the count in your query: select count(*)

Answer (score 0):

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string client = TextBox1.Text;
            string selected = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
            string calendar = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            string disease = txtDisease.Text;

```
        SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("insert into Appointment(Client_ID, DateofAppointment, TimeofAppointment, Disease) values(@Client_ID, @DateofAppointment, @TimeofAppointment, @Disease)", conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Client where Client_ID = @Client_ID", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client_ID", TextBox1.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                SqlCommand search = new SqlCommand("select * from Appointment where DateofAppointment = @DateofAppointment and TimeofAppointment = @TimeofAppointment", conn);
                search.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofAppointment", calendar);
                search.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeofAppointment", selected);
                Int32 count = (Int32)search.ExecuteScalar();
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Error!')</script>");
                }
                else
                {
                    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client_ID", client);
                    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofAppointment", calendar);
                    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeofAppointment", selected);
                    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Disease", disease);
                    insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    TextBox1.Text = "";
                    RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    txtDisease.Text = "";
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Appointment submitted! Please wait for your SMS confirmation. Thank you!')</script>");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "";
                RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = -1;
                txtDisease.Text = "";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('You are not a registered client!')</script>");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }


}
```

It's still not working... :(